# Nginx rule correction

Tags: url, nginx, rewriting

I want know if something is wrong in this rewrite rule :

```
rewrite ^/$lang/(.*)$ /$1?lang=$lang last;
```

Actually I've urls like that :

```
http://example.com/page1.php?lang=en
http://example.com/page2.php?lang=en
```

And I want urls like that :

```
http://example.com/en/page1.php
http://example.com/en/page2.php
```

Comment: Here's some nginx query string rewrites: http://serverfault.com/questions/488444/nginx-rewrite-convert-querystring-to-path

Comment: Regex could not contain variables.